# Not able to update TextView's text in custom dialog box

Tags: android, android-dialog

Please help. I have tried everything but failed every time. I am building an android app where I need to update text of a TextView in dialog box programmatically.
This dialog box is created using a custom layout. Posting code below, Please help in updating value of tv1 to "It's the new text". In XML layout file text was set to "old text".
After I run this program, the value of tv1 in 'dialogabt', is still seen as "old text".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

        //generating first dialog box 
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.setings);
                dialog1.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

function to generate the second dialog box and update TextView's text in it

```
public void abtit(View view) {
    Dialog dialogabt = new Dialog(this);
    dialogabt.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom2, null);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.firstapp);

    System.out.println("Going to set new value");
    tv1.setText("Its new text");
    System.out.println("done setting new value");

    dialogabt.setContentView(R.layout.custom2);
    dialogabt.show();
}
```

**settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/set3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="abtit"
        android:text="About app" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_alert2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstapp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:onClick="openapp2"
        android:text="old text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The only problem I found with your code is that you are not calling the method that creates the second dialog box. And thus the dialog box is not being made.

Comment: Second dialog box is being created by function abtit(). Its mentioned in setings.xml layout's onclick attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dialogabt.setContentView(R.layout.custom2);

TextView tv1 = (TextView) dialogabt.findViewById(R.id.firstapp);

System.out.println("Going to set new value");
tv1.setText("Its new text");
System.out.println("done setting new value");

dialogabt.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your **abtit()** method, you are setting value in one custom view and in alert dialog you are setting another view, so it will not affect the values which you have set for dialogView object.

So just change your below line,

```
    dialogabt.setContentView(R.layout.custom2);
```

By

```
    dialogabt.setView(dialogView);
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Remove following line because you are seting contentView after setting text to textView

```
dialogabt.setContentView(R.layout.custom2);
```

and add this line to below

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom2, null);
```

Comment: Where to place this line? I guess without this line my dialogbox will not take shape from custom2.xml. Have tried to place it before setting new value of tv1, But even that didn't helped.